# How can an employer force a former employee to update their linkedin?

Tags: united-states

What law, statute, or precedent can an employer use to force an employee to update their linkedin?

An employee has left the company but has not yet updated their linkedin. Is it possible to force them to update it?

If it is not possible, is there precedent or reasoning why?

Comment: Has the former employer already requested the profile to be updated? Presumably the only update they can request is to add a date of leaving.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not possible. If there are specific reasons for needing this, there might be an exception, but the question doesn't provide enough details to say.

Comment: Is your company suffering some actual damage from this? (For instance, if the ex-employee is going around using your name to defraud people.)

Answer (score 4):

### You have no leg to stand on unless your contract contained such a clause

If I want to force your employees to keep LinkedIn up to date, you need to make that a part of the contract, or have an extra contract that gives them an incentive to update their page - and make the contract valid at all.

### ...unless there's defamation or maybe fraud

You *might* have a cause in case mentioning you as the employer would be defamation, but that is an incredibly hard task: the fact that they were at one point employed by someone is a fact, and that is a nigh perfect shield against defamation. That case would be hard to nigh impossible to win without a lot of information or specific facts.

A slightly easier situation would be if they were using their actually ended but alleged ongoing employment to gain something from a 3rd party. That could be fraud to that 3rd party's damage, and that 3rd party could sue for the fraud. That would not have the listing updated, but the fraud case in which the employer was named a party *might* give rise to a valid defamation case against the ex-employee.

### Are there no laws against such claims? Not really...

Some jobs are special insofar as they allow to gain special merits. Some of these special merits are so special that many people grant benefits to those who have them. Yes, I am talking about military medals, which are pretty much an "I am/was a member of this organization" claim turned up to 11. And people that have these merits fight vigorously to keep them protected.

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)[first-amendment](/questions/tagged/first-amendment)
However, only **using those special merits to gain benefits** is illegal, and technically already fraud. It is however **not** illegal to claim you got the merit if you don't profit from it. That is the direct outcome of [US v Alvarez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Alvarez) and the [2013 revision of the Stolen Valor Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolen_Valor_Act_of_2013). The critical point here is, that the 2015 law here is that it needs to be *explicitly* for *gains* and is in effect a special variant of fraud - and **not** a restriction of free speech.

The reason for this comes from the [2005 Stolen Valor Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolen_Valor_Act_of_2005) being struck down in 2012 as a violation of free speech: It illegalized, among other things *wearing* of specific medals and wearing or displaying them. It however also impacted free speech by banning people from claiming to be awarded medals they hadn't, even if they did not wear the medal at all - which was what happened in Alvarez's case. In the opinion that struck down the 2005 law, Kennedy wrote:

> Permitting the government to decree this speech to be a criminal offense, whether shouted from the rooftops or made in a barely audible whisper, would endorse government authority to compile a list of subjects about which false statements are punishable. That governmental power has no clear limiting principle. Our constitutional tradition stands against the idea that we need Oceania’s Ministry of Truth.

Answer (score 2):

> How can an employer force a former employee do update their LinkedIn?
> What law, statute, or precedent can an employer use to force an employee to update their linkedIn?
> An employee has left the company but has not yet updated their linkedIn. Is it possible to force them to update it?

No, they can't, because there is no law that empowers one social media user to dictate what another social media user chooses to post.

LinkedIn may seem like a professional sort of site that companies could possibly have some say in the content, but it isn't.  It is just social media service with a job oriented theme.

Companies are just like employees, merely users of the site.  Individuals and groups are expected to comply with terms and community standards set by the site, but they are equals with no one group having any power over another.

Like any other medium, however, one user could pursue legal action against another under defamation laws if they suffered damage as a result of the contents of another user's postings.

> If it is not possible, is there precedent or reasoning why?

Yes:  Equality under the law, individual freedom of expression, etc.